# Maximising power received using two sets of data

Tags: data, graph, plot

I have done simulations where by I am varying two variables i.e. powerTransmit and frequency within an equation, for example:

powerReceived = powerTransmit - 20*log(frequency) - 20*log(distance)

The distance is kept constant.

I am runing a permutation menthod. So I first loop through all the frequencies first, then I increment the powerTransmit and then loop it.

I then get two sets of data. The first set is percentage of power received against the frequencies. The second set is percentage of power received againt powerTransmit. Now clearly the units do not match up. But how do I plot these two sets of data on the same axes. So I can find the point of intersection that maximizes the percentage of power received against the frequency and powerTransmit?

power received =

120 (%)       -> freq = 862(MHz), power = 30(dBm),

120       -> freq = 866, power = 30

180       -> freq = 862, power = 33,

180       -> freq = 866, power = 33

213       -> freq = 862, power = 34

213       -> freq = 866, power = 34

246       -> freq = 862, power = 36

246       -> freq = 866, power = 36

N.B the percentage going beyond 100% is expected in my simulations

Comment: Show results in dBm  Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 how can you convert the frequency to dBm? dBm is referenced to a milliwatt has nothing to do with frequency

Comment: From my understanding, you should have only one set of two-dimensional data, namely powerReceived(powerTransmit, frequency). Visualize it as a 2D array, in which each line corresponds to a powerTransmit value, and each column a frequency value. This could then be plotted as a 3D surface, or as a contour plot in 2D. If you're searching for a maximal, the contour plot would be most useful. If this is still unclear, provide value ranges in your question and I'll type up an answer.

Comment: @VicenteCunha I have updated my question

Comment: @Joey and what is distance?

Comment: @VicenteCunha distance is 3.2m

Comment: @Joey the common Horizontal axis is dBm  the 2 variables are 2 vertical axes. Since dBm is in a log scale,  the variables add to combine in path loss instead of multiplying in a linear scale

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 please look at the answer provided. Look at the simplicity compared to your complicated proposed answer. Now for me to explain you proposed answer in a report will indefinitely confuse the crap out of the marker, where as the answer provided. Which is concise and there's no need to much explanation. Please take all this into account when answering.

Comment: Joey. Please understand. There is no intersection, only additive signal vs Tx power and loss vs frequency.  Since you did not define a path loss budget, you fail to understand this concept.  What is your Rx threshold ? My answer is still relevant. Your comment is not. Nor will you understand until you comprehend my links on Friis and Path loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using matlab. First, set up value ranges:

```
distance = 3.2;
powerTransmit = linspace(30,36);
frequency = linspace(862e6,866e6);
```

'meshgrid' can be used to simplify loops:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(powerTransmit,frequency);
Z = X - 20*log10(Y) - 20*log10(distance);
```

Since it is not clear how to convert equation results to a percentage, I've used a linear mapping:

```
Z = (Z-min(min(Z)))*(246-120)/(max(max(Z))-min(min(Z))) + 120;
```

Now, a contour plot:

```
contour(X,Y/1e6,Z)
xlabel('powerTransmit [dBm]')
ylabel('frequency [MHz]')
title('powerReceived [%]')
colorbar
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can this also be applied to three variables x, y, z?

Comment: Yes, but a function in three variables would result in contour surfaces, a 3D plot instead of 2D. This usually results in a cluttered plot, but being creative with colors, anottations and orientation could do the trick.